# <img> does not show the image, even the directory is exact

Tags: smarty

I tried googling for hours, and haven't found a working solution. Why it isn't working? I tried to set the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` in my php file. But still didn't work. I also tried to prepend `./` and it is still not showing the image.
I tried the `{html_image}` too.

Comment: Show your code!

Answer (score 0):

index.tpl

```
<nav>
  <div> <img src="./cat.jpg" alt="none"/> </div>
  <div class="nav_buttons">Product</div>
  <div class="nav_buttons">Solutions</div>
  <div class="nav_buttons">Customers</div>
  <div class="nav_buttons">Pricing</div>
  <div class="nav_buttons">Company</div>
  <div class="nav_buttons">Resources</div>
  <div><span id="update">Send Me Updates</span></div>
</nav>
```

here my php

```
<?php

  include('../libs/Smarty.class.php');
  $smarty = new Smarty;

  $smarty->display('index.tpl');

?>
```